# What is wrong with the following MATLAB code?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

This is to remove certain elements in a matrix. I want 1:hseam and hseam:end.

```
for i=1:3                                                                  
    for j=1:cols                                                           
        if hseam(j)==1
            Img(:,j,i)=[im(2:rows,j,i)]; 
        elseif hseam(j)==rows
            Img(:,j,i)=[im(1:rows-1,j,i)];
        else            
            Img(:,j,i)=[im((1:hseam(j)-1),j,i) im((hseam(j)+1:end),j,i)];
        end
    end
end
```

This is the error am getting :

??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> reduceHeight at 17
            Img(:,j,i)=[im((1:hseam(j)-1),j,i) im((hseam(j)+1:end),j,i)];

Comment: @H.Muster no it does not. I means that `im((1:hseam(j)-1),j,i)` and `im((hseam(j)+1:end),j,i)` have different number of columns - you probably want `vertcat` here - so the two should be seperated by a colon.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to extract the *rows* 1:hseam and hseam:end (not exactly sure I understand the full intention of your code), you can also do:

```
Img = im([1:hseam, heasm:end],:,:)
```

No need for looping here...